# Firestore security rules. Allow reading a full collection (documents and subcollections)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been trying to make all documents in a subcollection be totally readable using these security rules:

```
 match /books {
     allow write, update, delete: if false; // This collection cannot be modified
  
     match /sells {
         allow read: if true; // All documents and sub-collections of this collection are readable
     }
 }
```

But when I try to read a document of the sell subcollection I get the Firebase permissions error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [match documents in the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#basic_readwrite_rules):

```
 match /sells/{doc} {
     allow read: if true; // All documents in sells are readable
 }
```

---

If you want to also match subcollection of the `sells` document, you can use a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) like this:

```
 match /sells/{doc=**} {
     allow read: if true; // All documents in and sub-collections of sells are readable
 }
```